# In React is it possible to pass a prop through a component and have it act as the prop name for a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to pass a prop from a parent component to a child component and have that prop act as the prop name with a Boolean value

eg.

App.js

```
 <Modal
        confirmColor = 'solidPrimary'
      />

OR

 <Modal
        confirmColor = 'solidSuccess'
      />
```

Desired Modal.js

```
const Modal = ({
  confirmColor
}) => {
  return (
       <Button
            {...confirmColor} // Should pass solidPrimary === true //
       />
  )
}
```

button would normally be rendered with Boolean values like this

```
      <Button
            solidPrimary
          />
```

ive tried a bunch of different ways to achieve this but have come up short every time!

Comment: I think you want to implement conditional rendering to your component. Please read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Thanks for replying Jerry. I had a very simplified version of the component there just to get the point across. I have conditional rendering using styled components. Figured it out anyway!

Answer (score 2):

By asking the question and typing it out helped to clear it up in my head. Simple really. Just after submitting I came up with the answer i needed

App.js

```
 <Modal
        confirmColor={{ solidPrimary: true }}
      />
```

Modal.js

```
<button
{...confirmColor}
/>
```

Comment: Fabulous! Happy coding :)